# Arduino powering to control sensors

Tags: power

I would like to know if it's possible to power up arduino by VIN pin (say 9v) and use 5v output pin to connect to a sensor.

Many thanks

Comment: Yes. It is. That's why it's called VIN. Voltage INput.

Comment: depends on how much current is required by the sensor to function correctly

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the replay! The sensor works with 5V but the manufacture says "External power supply (7~12V) is necessary to supply the microcontroller board when you using this CO2 sensor module."